# Convert date to closest end-of-month date MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date, financial

I need to convert a datenumber to its closest end-of-month date.  I found an online link but it is very inefficient for a large matrix (at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26374-round-off-dates-and-times).  Does Matlab (`Financial Toolbox`) has an inbuilt function for this?  I couldn't find it.

```
date_in = 734421 ;
somefunction(date_in) --> Sept 2010
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean closest end of month? 734421 is 10 Oct 2010, and you want that to be Sept 2010? So would 28 Sept 2010 be Oct 2010?

Comment: Yes Yoda.  Imagine that you have financial data available and you have to use the nearest end-of-month exchange rates. Thanks!

Comment: ??? Why is end of September 2010 not closer to 28 Sep 2010 than Oct 2010???

Comment: ... I think I might get it now: can "end" can also mean "before beginning" in your case? If you have a day in September, you want the closest month (either before or after) which is NOT September itself?

Comment: @Jonas Heidelberg: That's how I interpreted it based on the comments above: closest preceding or following month. Seems a little odd, but it sounds like what the OP wants.

Comment: @gnovice I'm wondering whether one should change the title / text of the question. To me "end-of-month" is really misleading for what is actually being asked here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some errors in my previous version. Here's the logic incorporated into a function. It also checks for the month and updates accordingly.

```
function out = roundMonth(dateNumber)
    dateVector = datevec(dateNumber);
    day = dateVector(3);
    month = dateVector(2);
    year = dateVector(1);

    month = month + sign(day - 15 + double(~(month-2)))...
        + double(~(day-15 + double(~(month-2))));

    dateVector(1) = year + double((month-12)==1) - double((1-month)==1);
    dateVector(2) = mod(month,12) + 12*double(~mod(month,12));

    out = datestr(dateVector,'mmm yyyy');
```

#### EXAMPLES:

1.

```
roundMonth(datenum('10-Oct-2010'))

ans =

Sep 2010
```

2.

```
roundMonth(datenum('20-Oct-2010'))

ans =

Nov 2010
```

3.

```
roundMonth(datenum('20-Dec-2010'))

ans =

Jan 2011
```

4.

```
roundMonth(datenum('10-Jan-2010'))

ans =

Dec 2009
```

Comment: In addition, you want to be careful about edge cases like common/leap years with 28/29 days in February, so its not always comparing against 15... It is never easy dealing with dates!

Comment: @Amro: Agreed, dates are always messy. For February you just replace 15 by 14, and 28/29 is the same as 30/31. One has to settle for either 15 or 16 (or 14/15 in Feb) as midpoint, and the choice is arbitrary. I've updated to account for February and the change in year (prev Dec or next Jan).

Comment: Also - this only deals with a single date. It can't handle an array of dates.

Comment: @Marc: `datestr` does not handle vectors well. However, that part can be easily addressed by writing your own conversion function. Alternately, you can use `arrayfun` to operate on an array.

Comment: ... your `~(month-2)` stuff is to deal with the special case February, right?

Comment: @Jonas: That's right. If it's February, subtract by 14 instead of 15.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, it sounds like you are asking for whether a given date is closer to the preceding or following month. You can greatly simplify the logic involved if you use the functions [EOMDAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eomday.html) to find the date for the end of the month and [ADDTODATE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/addtodate.html) to shift the current month up or down by one. Here's an example function that takes a date number as input:

```
function closestString = closest_month(dateNumber)

  dateVector = datevec(dateNumber);
  daysInMonth = eomday(dateVector(1),dateVector(2));
  if dateVector(3) > daysInMonth/2
    dateNumber = addtodate(dateNumber,1,'month');
  else
    dateNumber = addtodate(dateNumber,-1,'month');
  end
  closestString = datestr(dateNumber,'mmm yyyy');

end
```

Comment: +1 since it is **much** more understandable than yoda's solution and provides the same output on his four test cases ;-).